# Irish localized fieldname identifier unclear, Product recommendations Einstein

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, localization

I am searching for the right document to implement localized fields for Ireland.
English in Ireland or Irish in Ireland, or both if it differs.

We got this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_localized_recommendations.htm&type=5) from salesforce, which links to this [site](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) (Last updated 2017) -> Which does not help at all.

From earlier stages of Development I know some of the right localization IDs, because i asked Einstein Developers, but their answers do not correspond to the table at all.

Correct ones for ProductName:

- locale_de-DE_ProductName, German in Germany
- locale_it-IT_ProductName, Italian in Italy
- locale_nl-NL_ProductName, Dutch in Netherlands
- locale_fr-FR_ProductName, French in France
- locale_en-GB_ProductName, English in Great Britain
- locale_da-DA_ProductName, Danish in Denmark
- more from Europe...

What do i have to set for irish in Irland?

- locale_en-IE_ProductName?
- locale_ga-IE_ProductName?
- locale_ga-GE_ProductName?

Is there a correct table somewhere for all language and country combinations?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think it would `ga-GE`, but not sure. This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=icu_migration_format_changes.htm&type=5) about new localization formats seems to indicate this, but doesn't specifically mention anything in reference to or as a limitation with Einstein. Also, looks like these format might not be available for all the orgs created before Winter'20.

Comment: The language support for the Salesforce Platform generically is documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=5). Of course, that may not be relevant for Einstein since it may not have been unified. This shows en_IE for English (Ireland) and "ga" for Irish.

Comment: It can be any five digit locale you want as long as it matches in the catalog and the rec call

Comment: I thought so EazyE, but the salesforce engagement team once told me, that i have to use specific column names. I guess they were unsure themselves... wish i had had better solution architects at the beginning. Where were you at that time @Lukas Lunow :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like solved, because it seems to behave like EazyE comment suggests.

Comment: Could you include that comment in your answer here? Ya know, just in case.